# Django form label

Tags: django-forms

I want to customize django form labels in this way:

---

```
       ____
Time: |____| (min)
```

---

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the help_text field : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#help-text